# Why am I getting errors when I run this code involving pandas in a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I'm a new programmer and I'm just starting to use pandas, albeit in a jupyter notebook, and I'm having difficulties. When I run this code it returns a whole load of errors, and I don't know what to do. I would like the code to go through a csv file, find data entries that are either nulls or duplicates, and send a message to the screen saying that there are nulls or duplicates. There is no need to have the code fix the nulls or duplicates. Sorry about the poor code quality, I'm just getting to know python!

Here's the code:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Zak\Desktop\dup and nul data.csv")
# This would select the rows that have any null values in them.
null_rows = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]

# This would select rows that are duplicates
duplicate_rows = df[df.duplicated()]
```

And here's the csv file data I'm using:

```
ID,Name,DOB,Disability?,Age,Target Grade,Exam Mark
1,Alice Smith,12/03/2001,Y,14,B,23
2,Bob (Robert) Cork,01/09/2000,,15,A,47
3,Clare View,05-Oct-00,Yes,15,C,34 ½
4,Dave Reckoning,20-Jun-01,N,14,A*,70
4,Emma Genius,12/12/2000,No,15,A star,
```

I did wonder whether it's to do with my filepath, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the errors! Error messages are your friend, they are trying to tell you what's wrong. (They may not always succeed, but they try ;))

Comment: ok here you go:

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position 3: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-6c70618bc4db> in <module>
      1 import pandas
      2 
----> 3 df = pandas.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Zak\Desktop\dup and nul data.csv")
      4 # This would select the rows that have any null values in them.
      5 null_rows = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]

Comment: Please edit it into your question and format it as code; it's hard to find and hard to read in a comment.

Comment: What is the encoding of this CSV file? Apparently it's not in UTF-8, and it probably goes wrong on the `½` character.